# regex matching !important styles

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches any semicolon symbol `;` that doesn't start with `!important` or `!important`

For instance, if I have the following string:

```
.myclass {
  width: 400px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 20px !important;
  padding: 20px !important ;
  top: 1px;
}
```

I want to match those lines:

```
  width: 400px;
  color: #333;
  top: 1px;
```

So I can then run replace on them and add the `!important` attribute to them.

How should I write the regex that would match this?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this one: `(?!.*!important).*;`.
Breaking it down into smaller pieces we are using a negative lookahead `(?!<pattern>)` to say we want to match where there is NOT the match later in the string.  After that, we just need to look for any chars up until we see a closing `;`.  The way the negative lookahead is setup, if the line is ending in the `;` and there is a match to `!important` at all it will fail, no matter how many spaces are inbetween.  Since CSS can have spaces, this handles a lot more cases you could see other then 0 or 1 spaces.

If you wanted it to be EXACTLY like the original post where you are checking for zero or one space after `!important` but before `;`, you can change the lookahead to include `\s?;`, after `!important` of course.  This is checking for ANY whitespace, zero or one of, followed directly by the `;`.

Comment: Thanks! This will match the whole line, how can I only match the ; symbol? I want to perform replace operation on ; symbol like `style.replace(/(?!.*!important).*;/g, "!important;");` 
Thanks!

Comment: @Aljaz to clarify, you want to capture only the `;`, but only on these special lines?  The way it sounds, is you want to add in these `!important` tags before the `;`, but ONLY where they don't already exist... am I correct in understanding this?

Comment: exactly, yes. I want to append !important to all style attributes where its missing.

Comment: @Aljaz if you surround the semi colon in the match in `()` it will have those groups be returned then you can manipulate.

Comment: yeah, I know about that, but is there any way to run regex so that I can call regex replace function directly to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me at a [Regex tester](http://regexpal.com/):

```
.+[^((?!important)\s];
```

The regex matches any number of characters (`.+`) except the ones with !important in it (`[^!important]`).

Comment: This won't work. The square bracket will match only one character and not the word "!important".

Answer (score 0):

If this is entirely in one string variable

```
.myclass {
  width: 400px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 20px !important;
  padding: 20px !important ;
  top: 1px;
}
```

then you can split it on the new-line:

```
String[] lines = input.split(System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n"));
```

Then, skipping the first and last elements (which contain the curly-braces), only get lines that do *not* match `"!important ?;"`

```
Matcher importantMtchr = Pattern.compile("!important ?;").matcher("");
for(int i = 1; i < lines.length - 1; i++)  {
   String line = lines[i];
   if(!importantMtchr.reset(line).find())  {
      System.out.println(line);
   }
}
```

Full code:

```
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class NotExclamationImportantLines  {
   public static final String LINE_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");

   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      String input = new StringBuilder().
         append("myclass {"                 ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("width: 400px;"             ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("color: #333;"              ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("margin: 20px !important;"  ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("padding: 20px !important ;").append(LINE_SEP).
         append("top: 1px;"                 ).append(LINE_SEP).
         append("}"                         ).toString();

      //Split on the newline
      String[] lines = input.split(LINE_SEP);

      //Skip over the first and last elements, and only
      //print out those that don't contain the regular
      //expression `"important! ?"
      Matcher importantMtchr = Pattern.compile("!important ?;").matcher("");
      for(int i = 1; i < lines.length - 1; i++)  {
         String line = lines[i];
         if(!importantMtchr.reset(line).find())  {
            System.out.println(line);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
width: 400px;
color: #333;
top: 1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*!important\s*;).*?(;)\s*$
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^
           (1)          (2)
```

1. **Negative Lookahead assertion:** Find lines that do *not* contain `!important` followed by zero or more whitespace characters followed by a semicolon.
2. **Capture Group:** In the lines that pass the negative-lookahead test, capture *only* a semicolon at the end that is followed by zero or more whitespace characters.

See the [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/bM3bO0).