# regex Adding !important (if not exist) before semicolon

Tags: javascript, regex

I have html element as a string and I have to add "!important" before each ';' if still not exist.

I'm using this regex :

```
/[^!important(\s*)];(?=[^<>]+:|\s*")/g
```

Lets slice this regex, the first part:

```
[^!important(\s*)];
```

Checking if there is no "!important" before the ';'.
`(\s*)` inside allows to add spaces between the "!important" to the ';'.

The second part of the regex :

```
(?=[^<>]+:|\s*")
```

I don't sure about it, but I believe it finds all the ';' in the string.

Finally, I use javascript 'replace' to make this changes.

```
 var str3 = str.replace(/[^!important(\s*)];(?=[^<>]+:|\s*")/g, '!important;')
```

I used the question posed here :
[regex matching !important styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299511/regex-matching-important-styles)
And with some changes, I got the following result :
https://jsfiddle.net/7bhmjapL/19/

Few problems :

1. This regex finds the ';' that not follows after "!important", but it marks the ';' and one character that came before. For example : `"color:yellow;"` -> it marks : `"w;"`.
2. Further to the problem number one - If I have space between the "yellow" to ';', like this : `"color:yellow ;"`, it not recognized as a string that I have to add "!important".

I tried to play with the spaces, allow to add \t, \s, remove them and  lot of tries without success. The main problem is that the regex marks 2 characters instead of only the semicolon.

Comment: When one tries to solve a problem with `!important` - they create another even worse problem and there is no `!very-important` to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the problem from the other side - remove optional existing `!important` and add `!important` at the end of the line:

```
str.replace(/\s*(!important)?\s*;/g, ' !important;')
```

Comment: That's great ! Just remove the '$' at the end of the regex, it needless.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the line doesn't contain `!important` with `indexOf()` method, if so just replace the `;` character with `!important ;` :

```js
var str = "flaot: left;";
if (str.indexOf("!important") === -1) {
  str = str.replace(";", " !important;");
}
alert(str);
```

---

Or even **better** you can just use `replace()` method with the following regex:

```js
var str = "flaot: left;";
str = str.replace(/\s*(!important)?\s*;/g, " !important;");
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way maybe

Replace `!important;` by `;`

```
s/\!important\s*;/;/g
```

then

replace `;` by `!important;`

```
s/;/\!important;/g
```